# Keeping images together/stick images

Tags: html, css, image

Each image is a link so no I wont make them a sprite/one image.

I want them to be together with no spaces. Heres the codepen link:

```
<html>
      http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJXXxJ
</html>
```

Comment: i've put codeopen in html tags because stackoverflow didnt let me add codepen link.

Comment: What's the question again? Sounds like you need to take a look at `padding` and `margin`.

Comment: both @smoggers (kinda like windows 8/10)

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I need to connect them/stick them, (like buttons in windows 8)

Comment: @Filip something like this: http://codepen.io/Smoggs/pen/pJXXMy

Comment: Please give a better description of what you want to achive. Draw a picture or something. Also why do you make so many `<ul>`s?

Comment: because when I make one <ul> and put all pictures in there, all images will  do a rollover effect when you do just roll over one.

Comment: Here's the pic:http://prntscr.com/87oqpd

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some CSS I don't have time to fix the issue but try using css with things like

```
#druga{
margin-left: 400px;
margin-right: 100px;
margin-top:10px
}
```

your code will be different and it probably won't be druga, also find a youtube tutorial on how to use css https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz2klMXDqF4